# Swift NSDirectoryEnumerator Generator

Tags: swift

When I use

```
let fileEnumerator = self.fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(diskCacheURL,
    includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys,
    options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles, 
    errorHandler: nil)

for fileURL in fileEnumerator {

}
```

I get error:

> 'NSDirectoryEnumerator' does not have a member named 'Generator'

How can I enumerate through all elements in `NSDirectoryEnumerator`.

Comment: like    for fileURL in fileEnumerator.allObjects { } ?